# bootstrap-daterangepicker fills text field with today's date by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="received-date" name="received-date" required="required" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
```

and

```
$('.date-picker').daterangepicker({
          singleDatePicker: true,
          locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
          },
        });
```

When I initially load the page the input field is filled with today's date. How do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Add autoUpdateInput: false like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date-picker').singleDatePicker();
});

$.fn.singleDatePicker = function() {
  $(this).on("apply.daterangepicker", function(e, picker) {
    picker.element.val(picker.startDate.format(picker.locale.format));
  });
  return $(this).daterangepicker({
   singleDatePicker: true,
   autoUpdateInput: false
  });
};
```

Comment: This will completely disable the datepicker from populating the input field.